# How to upgrade version of an installed package on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos6, yum, rpm

I installed `libtiff` by command `yum install libtiff-devel.x86_64` which installed ver `3.9.4`.

[anthony@server ~]$ sudo yum list installed | grep "libtiff"
libtiff.x86_64                     3.9.4-10.el6_5                      @updates 
libtiff-devel.x86_64               3.9.4-10.el6_5                      @updates

**Question**

However, I wish to have version `4.0.3`. How can I get the version I want?

**What I've tried**

I tried adding these rpm's I found for `4.0.3` http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libtiff but when I try, I get an error saying failed dependencies:

```
[anthony@server ~]$ rpm -Uvh ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/sourceforge/o/os/osolinux/update/RPMS.l/libtiff-4.0.3-17_Oso.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/sourceforge/o/os/osolinux/update/RPMS.l/libtiff-4.0.3-17_Oso.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by libtiff-4.0.3-17_Oso.x86_64
    libjbig.so.2.0()(64bit) is needed by libtiff-4.0.3-17_Oso.x86_64
    liblzma.so.5()(64bit) is needed by libtiff-4.0.3-17_Oso.x86_64
    libtiff.so.3()(64bit) is needed by (installed) wxGTK-2.8.12-1.el6.centos.x86_64
    libtiff.so.3()(64bit) is needed by (installed) wxGTK-gl-2.8.12-1.el6.centos.x86_64
    libtiff.so.3()(64bit) is needed by (installed) qt-x11-1:4.6.2-28.el6_5.x86_64
    libtiff.so.3()(64bit) is needed by (installed) gtk2-2.20.1-4.el6.x86_64
    libtiff.so.3()(64bit) is needed by (installed) opencv-2.0.0-12.el6.x86_64
    libtiff.so.3()(64bit) is needed by (installed) ImageMagick-6.5.4.7-7.el6_5.x86_64
    libtiff.so.3()(64bit) is needed by (installed) libtiff-devel-3.9.4-10.el6_5.x86_64
    libtiff.so.3()(64bit) is needed by (installed) cups-libs-1:1.4.2-52.el6_5.2.x86_64
    libtiffxx.so.3()(64bit) is needed by (installed) libtiff-devel-3.9.4-10.el6_5.x86_64
    libtiff = 3.9.4-10.el6_5 is needed by (installed) libtiff-devel-3.9.4-10.el6_5.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On CentOS 6 you will need to build and install it from source, or make your own packages.

If you can upgrade to CentOS 7 you can get 4.0.3 from the CentOS repositories.

Comment: I thought this page (http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libtiff) suggested that there are certain RPMs i can get which will let me do it..

Comment: how can I uninstall the current `3.9.4` version before I start building it from scratch?

Comment: `yum remove libtiff`

Comment: building it from source is a nightmare. it has so many dependencies.

Comment: CentOS isn't geared towards the latest and greatest, especially when you're running the previous release. If you can upgrade to CentOS 7 or run Debian or Ubuntu Server you'll have an easier time of it.